# On the coexistence of *ever* and *yet* in 'you haven't *ever* heard Charly, Sharon, Cameron and so on *yet*'

Tags: time

> Clearly, you haven't *ever* heard Charly, Sharon, Cameron and so on *yet*.

- Can *ever* and *yet* correctly coexist in the above sentence?
- If yes, can we suppress one of them without change in meaning?
- If not, why not?

Comment: So close, mate.

Comment: I can't answer this because it's on hold, but here's my answer: You're correct that the highlighted words are redundant and I would consider them nonstandard in written English. In spoken language, I can easily imagine hearing this sentence--the speaker might start the sentence, "Clearly, you haven't ever heard..." and then at the end feel that the timing needs more emphasis--haven't heard of them *yet*. Deleting either is preferable--even in speaking, their coexistence doesn't really sound more natural than either one in isolation.

Comment: The time references are skewed. Ever = at any time.   Yet= so far, as of now.   *Have you at any time tasted Jaegermeister up until now? (doesn't work)

Comment: Should be reopened, since it has been edited and it is clear what the OP is asking.

Comment: @CynicallyNaive Comments are not meant to be workarounds for answers. Please do not post an answer as a comment. You should've instead asked this to be reopened.

Comment: Thank you for the information! Sorry to impinge on the standards of your site, even if it's not the way I would organize a site. This isn't the place for me, but I wish everyone the best and hope a lot of good learning takes place!

Answer (score 1):

As a Native (Canadian) English speaker, having the both of them in one sentence sounds incorrect. Even though they both technically have the same meaning, 'yet' carries an implication that you will hear them in the future, while 'ever' does not - although it doesn't rule out such an event either.

If you are going to continue with how the listener should go hear Charly, Sharon, and Cameron, you could use either 'ever' or 'yet', but not both, and still be correct. Otherwise, it would be better to use 'ever'.